# I got a syntax error when trying to call JPA function

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

When Im trying to call JPA function this statement I got an error: syntax error at or near ":"

```
 public interface BcaTestRepository extends CrudRepository<InBodyBCA, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM in_body_bca bca WHERE person_id = :personId " +
      "AND to_timestamp(bca.datetimes::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  BETWEEN :startRange AND :endRange",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<InBodyBCA> findAllByPersonId(@Param("personId") Long personId,
                                    @Param("startRange") LocalDateTime startRange,
                                    @Param("endRange") LocalDateTime endRange);
```

But in PgAdmin the query works fine

```
SELECT id, to_timestamp(datetimes::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as dt FROM in_body_bca WHERE to_date(datetimes::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
BETWEEN '2018-05-07' AND '2019-05-07' ORDER BY to_date(datetimes::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') DESC ;
```

Comment: What data type is `bca.datetimes`? Casting to text combined with `to_timestamp()` doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the double colon here: `bca.datetimes::text`. JPA would look for `text` variable name.

You need to escape it:

```
bca.datetimes\\:\\:text
```

Comment: Sorry! It actually did help! Thank you!

Comment: @user3693537:  Alternatively: `cast(bca.datetimes as text)`